# Testing react-router (with Enzyme) with initialEntries

Tags: react-router, enzyme

I'm having an issue testing `react-router` starting with an `initialEntries` value - the following test fails, and I'm not sure why or what I'm doing wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import { MemoryRouter, BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/* eslint react/prefer-stateless-function: "off" */
class TestApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/nothome" render={() => 'AWAY'} />
          <Route path="/" exact render={() => 'HOME'} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

describe('react-router works with enzyme', () => {
  it('works with enzyme with starting location', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/nothome']} initialIndex={0}><TestApp /></MemoryRouter>);
    assert.isTrue(wrapper.html().includes('AWAY'), wrapper.html());
  });
});
```

The test fails with the following:

```
● react-router works with enzyme › works with enzyme with starting location

    AssertionError: <div>HOME</div>: expected false to be true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand now... wrapping the component in `<MemoryRouter>` doesn't override the existing `<Router>` component. The following test passes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/* eslint react/prefer-stateless-function: "off" */
class TestApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route path="/nothome" render={() => 'AWAY'} />
        <Route path="/" exact render={() => 'HOME'} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

describe('react-router works with enzyme', () => {
  it('works with enzyme with starting location', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/nothome']} initialIndex={0}><TestApp /></MemoryRouter>);
    assert.isTrue(wrapper.html().includes('AWAY'), wrapper.html());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Was struggling on that

Comment: removing <Router> from a component to make a test pass does not look like a good solution

Comment: Yeah, you may be right - but if I remember correctly I tried a lot of things to get this to work AND... a lot of time has passed and the tech has undoubtedly changed to the point that this question / answer is obsolete... I'm not working on this anymore to make it any better :-)